# Drag & Drop JQuery UI como ocultar Div após drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Estou tentando fazer a seguinte operação, tenho 3 divs uma Droppable e 2 Draggable, quero que quando eu arrastar uma das draggables e soltar em cima da droppable a Draggable seja ocultada parando de ser exibida na tela.

```
<div id="" class="droppable">Droppable</div>
<div id="" class="draggable">Draggable 1</div>
<div id="" class="draggable">Draggable 2</div>
```

No caso na hora que eu dropar a Div de classe draggable em cima da droppable ele teria que distinguir entre a Draggable 1 ou a Draggable 2 e ocultar a correta.

se alguém souber ou tiver ideia de como fazer isso e puder postar os código seria ótimo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O drop tem um evento `drop`que dispara uma função do jQuery, essa função tem dois parametros, um deles o objeto `ui` que contem o elemento que foi "largado". Assim dentro dessa função só precisa esconder o elemento (`.hide()` no meu exemplo) ou removê-lo.

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    ui.draggable.hide()
}
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y36QT/).
[Documentação](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop).

Comment: Perfeito, obg :)